# django queryset - corresponding ordering

Tags: django, django-models

I am quite new to django in general and have been going through the QuerySet documentation. However, one question seems to bug me a bit. So, for example, I do:

```
objects = MyModel.objects.all().filter(some_field = false)
```

then, I do the following:

```
var1 = objects.values_list('pk', flat=True)
var2= objects.values_list('field2', flat=True)
var3= objects.values_list('field3', flat=True)
```

My question is - do `var1`, `var2` and `var3` maintain the same corresponding orders? So:

```
var1[0], var2[0], var3[0]
```

are definitely the row entries of the DB table? i.e `var1`, `var2` and `var3` maintain their orders? I did try and few examples and it does look like it, but I just wanted to be sure.

Hope the question is clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the ordering will be consistently the same as the ordering in the underlying `objects` queryset you created.

Comment: Thank you - it would be nuts if it didnt - but I wanted to be sure :) Thanks again - accepted your answer. Happy Xmas btw!

Answer (score 1):

`values_list` doesnot touch the order, it just returns the given field values in a list. this will have the same original order as when you retrieve another field on this model. just different data, thats it.

and by the way,

```
objects = MyModel.objects.all().filter(some_field = false)
```

is the same as

```
objects = MyModel.objects.filter(some_field = false)
```

just as a sidenote ;)

Comment: You too - happy xmas! :)